# Pandas: 52 week high from yahoo or google finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo, finance

Does anyone know if you can get the 52 week high in pandas from either yahoo or google finance?   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, please check out [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/remote_data.html). Here's an example:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

symbol = 'aapl'

end = datetime.datetime.now()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(weeks=52)

df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', start, end)

highest_high = df['High'].max()
```

Comment: Thanks.   Is it possible with out pulling all 52 weeks of data?   i.e. Do they store the 52 week high in a specific field.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use yfinance(from yahoo)

```
pip install finance
```

```
import yfinance as yf

stock = "JNJ"

dataframe = yf.download(stock, period="1y", auto_adjust=True, prepost=True, threads=True)

max = dataframe['High'].max()
```

Comment: pip install yfinance

Answer (score 1):

You could also use other libraries such as yahoo_fin. This one works better sometimes, it would depend on what you want to do, but it's good to bear in mind other possibilities : )

```
import yfinance as yf
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

stock = 'AAPL'

df = yf.download(stock, period="1y")
print("$",round(df['High'].max(), 2))

df2 = si.get_data(stock, interval="1mo")
print("$",round(df2['high'].tail(12).max(), 2))
```

Output:

```
$ 182.94
$ 182.94
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the info keyword to return lots of aggregated data like P/E Ratio, 52-Week High,etc.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
print(data.fiftyTwoWeekHigh)
```

Comment: was just going to add this. IMO it is best as it is already calculated.